# Coin tosses with unknown success probability

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a coin with **unknown** probability of success (let say Heads) $p$ which is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$.

I toss a coin $N$ times.

> What is the probability that I have got $n \leq N$ Heads?

Ok. I've calculated (using Wolfram) that it is exactly $\frac{1}{N+1}$, i.e. every $n$ is equiprobable.

> What is the intuitive explanation for this fact?

I can understand by symmetry argument, why getting $k$ Heads should be exactly the same as getting $k$ Tails. But why getting $0$ Heads is the same as getting $7$ Heads (in case $N \neq 7$) is well beyond me.

Update: Calculations involved:
$$P(\text{# of Heads} = k) = \int\limits_0^1 {N \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{N-k} dp, $$

solving it gives:
$$P(\text{# of Heads} = k) = {N \choose k} \frac{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(N-k+1)}{\Gamma(N+2)},$$

which turns out to be $\frac{1}{N+1}$.

Comment: Huh? What is your calculation? What is the prior? Is it the uniform prior?

Comment: @BrianTung, since you ask and I do not understand you, we can assume that indeed uniform.

Comment: What I mean is, are you assuming that $p$ is uniformly distributed *a priori*? I.e., before you start flipping, $p$ is equally likely to be any value between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @BrianTung, yes indeed.

Comment: Getting $0$ heads is precisely the same as getting $7$ heads... because that's the probability of getting $0$ tails.  See the symmetry?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork There's only symmetry if $N=7$, which I don't think is assumed.

Comment: @MishaLavrov there is symmetry always.

Comment: @Youem With an argument such as the one you've given, yes! I'm just saying that an argument like that needs to be made; the $k=0$ case is only *obviously* symmetric to the $k=N$ case.

Comment: Why do you integrate over $p$? are you considering a uniform prior $p$ and then want the marginal probability?

Comment: @qwr, I probably do not have enough background to understand your question. I think you should give an answer with an example to what you mean. For the matter of this question, $p$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course there is an intuition.

To see it let's ask the question differently. For that I will be considering $X_0, X_1,\ldots,X_{N}$ as $N+1$ independent uniform distributed random variables on $(0,1)$.

$X_0$ will be the probability of having heads.

The number of heads in your trials is exactly the number of $X_i$ smaller than $X_0$. So if you want to have $k$ heads you want $X_0$ to be ranked as the $k+1$-th element.

However there is no difference between $X_0$ and any other $X_j$. So ranking $X_0$ as the $k+1$-th element will have $1/(N+1)$ probability.

Comment: That is a good argument, I read it once and didn't understand it, but reading it again I think it's a very good way to look at this.

Comment: So you say: "Let first toss a probability of success", then "count as success everything that is tossed in range $[0, X_1]$". I like it for simplicity, but why is this a *different view* on the coin tosses? This is unclear.

Comment: Toss a coin with success probability $p$ is equivalent to generate a random variable uniform on $(0,1)$ and see if it smaller than $p$

Comment: It does need re-reading.  My thinking:  Let $H=\sum\limits_{i=2}^{N+1} \mathbf{1}_{X_i<X_1}$ be the resulting number of heads.  We have $\mathbb{P}(H=h \mid X_1=p) ={N \choose h}p^h(1-p)^{N-h}$ as a conditional binomial distribution, while $f_{X_1}(x)=1$ for $0 \le x \le 1$ and marginally   $\mathbb{P}(H=h) =\frac{1}{N+1}$ with integer $0 \le h \le N$ due to the exchangeability.  It might have been easier if the random variables had been $X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_N$

Comment: @Henry thank you for your comment. I find what you have wrote a rigorous way to put the answer. I did not write like that because the OP asks only for intuition. Do you think adding this to answer will make it clear?

Comment: Youem - as @SuzuHirose commented, it is not instantly obvious to me what you said, so I reread it and then wrote those notes to help me understand what you were saying.  For me, the intuitive bit is that you do not need to calculate the marginal   $\int_0^1   {N \choose h}p^h(1-p)^{N-h} \, dp$ since your model makes it clear it must be $\frac1{N+1}$.  I am happy to leave this in the comments, though I have edited your answer to make the special value $X_0$

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to make the answer clearer.

Answer (score 4):

> Ok. I've calculated (using Wolfram) that it is exactly $\frac{1}{N+1}$, i.e. every $n$ is equiprobable.

That result is correct, but we don't need no stinkin' Wolfram Alpha to do this.

> $$P(\text{# of Heads} = k) = \int\limits_0^1 {N \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{N-k} dp, $$

Well first of all
$$
\int\limits_0^1 {N \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{N-k} dp
={N \choose k}\int_0^1 p^k(1-p)^{N-k} dp
$$
Now the integral $Q(k,N)\equiv\int_0^1 p^k(1-p)^{N-k}dp$ can be done e.g. by integration by parts. If $k>0$ then
$$
\begin{align}
\int p^k(1-p)^{N-k}&=p^k\int (1-p)^{N-k}-k\int p^{k-1}\int(1-p)^{N-k+1}\\
&={1\over N-k+1}p^k(1-p)^{N-k+1}\biggr|_0^1\\
&\;\;\;\;\;\;+{k\over N-k+1}\int_0^1p^{k-1}(1-p)^{N-k+1}dp\\
&=0+{k\over N-k+1}Q(k-1,N)
\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
and if $k=0$ then $$Q(0,N)=\int_0^1 (1-p)^N dp={1\over N+1}\tag{2}$$
so using (1) and (2) $$Q(k,N)={k!(N-k)!\over (N+1)!}={1\over(N+1) {N\choose k}}.$$

> What is the intuitive explanation for this fact?

The obvious intuitive explanation for the probabilities all being ${1\over N+1}$ is that when we have no idea whatsoever what the probability of getting a head is on any trial, that is to say "there is a uniform distribution of probability of getting a head", then we have absolutely no idea whatsoever what outcome we will get on each trial, so the probability of getting $k$ heads on $N$ trials comes out to be exactly the same for all the different $k$s.

It's quite neat that the maths comes out like this.

Answer (score 4):

To be more explicit, what you are describing can be viewed in conditional probability with an [uninformative uniform prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Uninformative_priors) on $p$.

That is, first draw $p \sim U[0,1]$, then draw $k \mid p \sim \operatorname{Bin} (N,p)$.

As you are aware, conditional probability tells us

$$
P(k) = \int P(k \mid p) P(p)  dp 
$$

The other answers give good intuition: the uninformative prior in this case gives "no information" via $p$ of $k$, and it turns out in this case due to some mathematical symmetries of binomial distribution (the sum of independent Bernoulli trials) that if we know "nothing" about $p$ then we also know "nothing" about $k$ so it comes out as uniform.

And if I encountered this problem in real life and wanted to mathematically verify my intuition, there's actually a shortcut statisticians use to avoid any integrals:

Recall that [Binomial likelihood with Beta conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_discrete_distribution) (where continuous uniform distribution $U(0,1)$ is a special case $\operatorname{Beta}(1,1)$) has a [beta-binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) [posterior-predictive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution) (marginalizing over $p$), plug-in $\alpha = \beta = 1$,  and the discrete uniform distribution $U(0, N)$ again pops out :)

Comment: Fantastic answer, motivating the construction of the random variable over and beyond the result, and I think it gives a very decent and general explanation of the situation. Great stuff right here.